# convert .tflite to .pb model to test performance of tflite model on test tfrecords

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, object-detection-api, tensorflow2.x

I am currently working on object detection task.
Till TF1.2 we could use toco to get .pb file get back again from .tflite model file. Is there any solution in tf2.4 or tf2.5?

If not, how can i test .tflite model performance on test tf records?

Thank you,
Anshu

Answer (score 0):

You can read TFRecord file using some library such as tf.data or etc., and convert each data from there in np.float32 or np.something_array format so you can feed the data to tflite.interpreter.